# Django - remove www from URLs

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, no-www

I've added this to my `.htacces`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but then trying to reach `www.example.com` redirects me to:

`http://example.com/example/wsgi.py/`

because i have `WSGIScriptAlias / home/www/example.com/example/wsgi.py` directive in my `httpd.conf` and of course i get 404 error.

Eventually, i've managed to *fix* this by adding next line in my `urls.py`:

`url(r'^example/wsgi.py/$', index),` (so it redirects to home page)

but i'm not quite sure that this is the right way to do it (because when i try to reach `example.com` i see that web browser changes address quickly to `www.example.com` and then again to `example.com`)

If anyone would ask, yes i've seen [this](http://dryan.me/articles/remove-www-urls-django/) but this didn't help me either, because browser gets url recursive problem (example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com...)

**EDIT : FOLDER STRUCTURE**

This is my folder structure:

`\mysite\ 
        static\
        media\
        .htaccess
        manage.py
        mysite\
                 templates
                 templatetags
                 tinymce
                 static
                 urls.py
                 settigs.py
                 views.py
                 wsgi.py
                 models.py
                 forms.py
                 __init__.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it much simpler to accomplish no-www redirects with middleware that with with Apache mod_rewrite config.

The middleware that you linked to looks like it does the trick. I'm guessing your problems came from Apache config - make sure you remove all mod_rewrite commands (`Rewrite*` stuff) and then restart the apache server (ref. [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful) but check for your OS, might be specific).

There is only one additional tweak that you should to: make sure you don't redirect any POST requests, because that might result in lost data (tangent ref: [Why doesn't HTTP have POST redirect?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect)).

Anyways, this is what I use, worked quite well for me:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class NoWWWRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):

    if request.method == 'GET':  # if wanna be a prefect REST citizen, consider HEAD and OPTIONS here as well
        host = request.get_host()
        if host.lower().find('www.') == 0:
            no_www_host = host[4:]
            url = request.build_absolute_uri().replace(host, no_www_host, 1)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

To use it, put in a file somewhere, maybe `mysite/mysite/middleware.py`.
Then make sure it's run, in your `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'mysite.middleware.NoWWWRedirectMiddleware',
    # ... other middleware ...
```

If there is no `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your `settings.py` then copy the defaults from [here in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) but make you're looking at the correct version of Django, there are some changes in 1.7!

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer and explanations! I've tried as you suggested but i still have problems: with this middleware i'm able to open my site when I hit 'www.example.com', but just 'example.com' returns this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 90, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)

TypeError: process_request() takes exactly 5 arguments (2 given)
`

Comment: @frnhr: Coming from a different angle, would it be better (performance wise) to do this in the middleware as compared to doing it at the web server level?

Comment: Performance-wise it is better to do it earlier in the server stack (on Apache, nginx or what have you). Also make sure it is a permanent redirect, thanks user1940979 for pointing that out, see his answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered some time back but to add to the answer given above use

```
host.startswith('www.')
```

its more readable and also you should use permanent redirect to give the browser correct response header.

```
from django import http

class NoWWWRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        host = request.get_host()
        if host.startswith('www.'):
            if request.method == 'GET':  # if wanna be a prefect REST citizen, consider HEAD and OPTIONS here as well
                no_www_host = host[4:]
                url = request.build_absolute_uri().replace(host, no_www_host, 1)
                return http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified version that works with Django 1.11+ style middleware:

```python
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

class NoWWWRedirectMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.process_request(request)
        return response or self.get_response(request)

    def process_request(self, request):
        host = request.get_host()
        if host.startswith('www.'):
            if request.method == 'GET':
                no_www = host[4:]
                url = request.build_absolute_uri().replace(host, no_www, 1)
                    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Apache configuration works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=301,L]

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www/example.com/example/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/www/example.com/example

<Directory /home/www/example.com/example>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I'm unable to restart Apache server with `WSGIPythonPath /home/www/example.com/example`. Second, i had to `Require all granted` change to `Order deny,allow Allow from all` because im running 2.2 apache. Third, if i remove `WSGIPythonPath /home/www/example.com/example` apache is able to restart, but hitting www.example.com still gives me example.com/example/wsgi.py :(

Comment: What errors do you get if you use the WSGIPythonPath in the confid? Can you please describe your folder structure of your app in your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know what type of error is because i restart services through Webuzo control panel. It says only 'Service was unable to restart.' How can i check what type of error is? Sorry, i'm noob for apache.                                   I've added my folder structure.