# Consistent user authorization across url with/without www

Tags: django, web, no-www, www-authenticate

I need to clarify a fundamental concept (beginner here).

In a Django web app I maintain, I notice that if one logs in via going to `example.com`, *they remain logged out* on `www.example.com` (and can then go on to create a clone account).

1) Why does this happen?

2) What's the standard practice to iron out this issue? I.e., give one consistent experience across `www` and `no-www`.

In case the answer is as basic as just a redirection, I could use some pointers and an illustrative example there too - I'm using nginx reverse proxy with gunicorn.

Comment: I don't think any client-side stuff will prevent users from registering clone accounts, that has more to do with your models and views rather than cookies or auth stuff

Comment: also what are you doing to log the users in? are you using the builtin views or is it a custom login?

Comment: In the context of this question, cloning is just an observation - we can disregard it.

Comment: I rely on `django.contrib.auth` (i.e. inbuilt stuff from the Django framework).

Comment: unless you somehow rely on the contents of a cookie to set the username of new users, there is no reason why users would create clone accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 ) Django cookies do not work for same with a prepended www and non-www domain by default.Django considers it as a different sessions.

2) The [PREPEND_WWW](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#std:setting-PREPEND_WWW) setting you can set to redirect your xyz.com to www.xyz.com.

```
PREPEND_WWW = True
```

or if you need same cookie to both of the sites you can use [session_cookie_domain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#session-cookie-domain),

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".yoursite.com"
```

Comment: Yes that what django document says,Set it to a string such as ".example.com" (note the leading dot!) for cross-domain cookies, or use None for a standard domain cookie.

Comment: **1)** Is it standard practice to have `www` or to not have it? **2)** Some resources point out that such redirection should happen on the webserver level (nginx in my case). Is the approach you've defined better/worse than that?

Comment: It does not matter what you use www or not www , but when you decided one of them you have to be consistent because of SEO purpose.

Comment: but many major live projects use www to appended such as instagram and facebook

Comment: Thanks for the information. Lastly, what would you suggest to be the best way to make this change, with the least amount of disturbance for existing users?

Comment: i would suggest redirect all url hits to www prepended url

Comment: For the record, I ended up implementing this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29811817/4936905. I actually wanted to take the `no WWW` route.