# how to redirect a django website from www to non www

Tags: django, web, redirect

How to redirect a django website from www to Non www. i have already tried library of django pip install django-redirect-to-non-www But No working. Please guide us how to perform the redirection in django website.

Thank You

Comment: are you using apache2 for deployment ?

Comment: See also: [How to redirect www to no-www URL - Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909296/how-to-redirect-www-to-no-www-url-nginx) and [Nginx: Redirect non-www to www https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - remove www from URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359718/django-remove-www-from-urls)